# bash script locks when I execute it in background

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, gdb, jobs

I have two scripts:

script 1:

```
.......
./script2
....
```

script 2:

```
......
gdb ..... > /dev/null 2>&1
......
```

When I execute script, it works, but when I run it in backgroud, I get this message:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 ./script1 -params...
```

When I watch running the processes, there are script1, script2 and gdb, so gdb has just locked (it has command file with q, y commands). when I execute fg, gdb then finishes. after some time, it again prints `[1]+  Stopped` with gdb locked, after fg again continues....

What can be the problem?

EDIT: with

```
gdb ..... > /dev/null 2>&1 &
wait
```

it works

Answer (score 0):

> `[1]+  Stopped                 ./script1 -params...`

This happens when your program (or script) running in the background tries to read from terminal.

You likely want to run `gdb` with `--batch` flag, so it doesn't try to read its STDIN.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Although I'm passing file with `q`, `y` commands (and also quit confirmation is off, `y` command just for security). When I press `fg` to let it run in foreground, it start running without my input.